# Left shift operator $L: l^2 \rightarrow l^2$ on the sequence space $l^2$

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, abstract-algebra

$$L: l^2 \rightarrow l^2$$ is defined by $$b = (b_1,b_2,...) \mapsto Lb = (b_2,b_3,...)$$. $(Lb)_n = b_{n+1}$ respectively.

How can I determine the adjoint endomorphism $L^*$?

Kind regards
George

Comment: Hint: $L^*(b_1,b_2,\ldots) = (0,b_1,b_2,\ldots)$ see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator

Answer (score 1):

The inner product on $\ell^2$ is given by $(a, b) = \sum a_i b_i$. Thus you need the operator $L^*$ with
$$(a, L^*b) = (La, b) = a_2 b_1 + a_3 b_2 + \dots.$$
In particular,
$$(L^*b)_i = (e_i, L^*b) = \begin{cases}
b_{i-1} & \text{if }i > 1; \\
0 & \text{if $i = 1$,}
\end{cases}$$
where $e_i\in \ell^2$ is the sequence with $(e_i)_j = \delta_{ij}$ (Kronecker delta).

Comment: $L$ is the left-shift, $L^*$ the right-shift operator.